# I can not use " putStr "\ESC[2J" " in Haskell

Tags: haskell, emacs

I run the code

```
putStr "\ESC[2J"
```

on mac book air, but the buffer screen of emacs did't be cleared. Is there other code instead of

```
putStr "\ESC[2J"
```

to clean the screen?

Comment: Maybe it's a buffering issue? Try adding `hFlush stdout` after that. I have no idea however about how emacs handles that.

Comment: You might want to try it outside of Emacs (unless you specifically want it to work inside Emacs).

Comment: I can use putStr "\ESC[2J" outside of Emacs ! Thank you for your advises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>C-c C-k</kbd> should clear the screen for repl.

You can also clear the screen with the command <kbd>C-c M-o</kbd>